# Firebase: Not able to receive notification on my web browser

Tags: javascript, laravel, firebase, firebase-notifications

I am using `Laravel 5.4`, I have just started learning `firebase messaging` and I want to get the `notification` on my web-browser if someone sends it.

What I've implemented is, in a `master page` I have imported `firebase scripts` as below:

**resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php:**

```
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    firebase.initializeApp({
        'messagingSenderId': '1***************2' //i.e.My firebase key
    });

    const messaging = firebase.messaging();

</script>

{{ HTML::script('firebase-messaging-sw.js')}} // This script file is there in the public (i.e. root) directory

<script type="text/javascript">
    messaging.onMessage(function(payload){
        console.log('onMessage', payload);
    });
</script>
```

And

**firebase-messaging-sw.js:**

```
if ('serviceWorker' in navigator) {

    console.log("serviceWorker exists");

    navigator.serviceWorker.register('/../firebase-messaging-sw.js')
    .then((registration) => {
        messaging.useServiceWorker(registration);

        messaging.requestPermission()
        .then(function() {
            console.log('requestPermission Notification permission granted.');
            return messaging.getToken();
        })
        .then(function(token) {
            console.log("requestPermission: ", token); // Display user token
        })
        .catch(function(err) { // Happen if user deney permission
            console.log('requestPermission: Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
        });

        // Get Instance ID token. Initially this makes a network call, once retrieved
        // subsequent calls to getToken will return from cache.
        messaging.getToken()
        .then(function(currentToken) {
            if (currentToken) {
                console.log("getToken", currentToken);
            } else {
                // Show permission request.
                console.log('getToken: No Instance ID token available. Request permission to generate one.');
            }
        })
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log('getToken: An error occurred while retrieving token. ', err);
        });

        // Callback fired if Instance ID token is updated.
        messaging.onTokenRefresh(function() {
            messaging.getToken()
            .then(function(refreshedToken) {
                console.log('onTokenRefresh getToken Token refreshed.');
                console.log('onTokenRefresh getToken', refreshedToken);
            })
            .catch(function(err) {
                console.log('onTokenRefresh getToken Unable to retrieve refreshed token ', err);
            });
        });

        // [START background_handler]
        messaging.setBackgroundMessageHandler(function(payload) {
            console.log('[firebase-messaging-sw.js] Received background message ', payload);
            // Customize notification here
            const notificationTitle = 'Background Message Title';
            const notificationOptions = {
                body: 'Background Message body.',
                icon: '/firebase-logo.png'
            };

            return self.registration.showNotification(notificationTitle, notificationOptions);
        });
        // [END background_handler]
    });
}
else {
    console.log("serviceWorker does not exists");
}
```

With console log on browser, I am getting messages `requestPermission Notification permission granted.` and `get token` along with a token generated.

In Mozilla firefox, it seems everything OK but in chrome I am getting this javascript error:

```
controller-interface.js:137 
Uncaught (in promise) e 
{
    code: "messaging/only-available-in-sw", 
    message: "Messaging: This method is available in a service worker context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw).", 
    stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available…irebase-messaging-sw.js:67:19)"
}
code: 
"messaging/only-available-in-sw"message: "Messaging: This method is available in a service worker context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw).
"stack: "FirebaseError: Messaging: This method is available in a service worker context. (messaging/only-available-in-sw) at t.e.setBackgroundMessageHandler (https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/4.8.1/firebase-messaging.js:6:11342) ..."
```

Now, to send message I am using post-man:

```
Request type: post
URL: https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send
Headers: Authorization: key=AAA*****fg // i.e. my authorization token
Body: 
{
  "notification": {
    "title": "Some title",
    "body": "Some body",
    "icon": "firebase-logo.png",
    "click_action": ""
  },
  "to": "f3ea******q" //token generated by firebase using getToken method
}
```

And I am getting a success response as:

```
{
    "multicast_id": 5************1,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "https://updates.push.services.mozilla.com/m/gAAAAA***********byb"
        }
    ]
}
```

But, however I am not able to get the notification on my browser. If the notification is received then it must console log the statements I have put in `setBackgroundMessageHandler` or `messaging.onMessage` methods.

Am I missing or misconfigured something? 
P.S. All these codes are running on HTTPS on my linux server.

Comment: Any experts available on Stackoverflow now-a-days?

Comment: just a guess but is your `firebase-messaging-sw.js` able to find `messaging`?  I think `messaging` miiiight need to be only initialized in the service worker, not sure yet.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using the {{ HTML::script('firebase-messaging-sw.js')}}

Use `<script src="/firebase-messaging-sw.js"></script>`

From backend You need to make curl request:

```
$url='http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send';
$fields =array("registration_ids"=> $registration_id,"data"=> $message, 
 "priority"=>'high');
$headers = array('Authorization: key=xxxxxx','Content-Type: 
   application/json');
// Open connection
$ch = curl_init();
// Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

You have to make curl request with a proper payload as firebase compliance.
I have used $registration_id in the fields object, which means generated fcm_token to that particular device/web app.

Comment: No luck. I have updated the script tag and send a sample request using Post-man as described in https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive . The requests gets send successfully and also it is returning multicast_id with success flag true. But at client side, however I am not able to receive the notification.

Comment: Have you send the registered device fcm token in parameter.

Comment: Yes of course. The request body is: ```{ 
 "notification": {
  "title": "Background Message Title",
  "body": "Background message body",
  "click_action" : "https://dummypage.com"
 },
 "to" : "f6KPKuqSeCU*************************************f"
}```, URL: ```https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send```, Headers: ```Authorization:key=AAAA************************************************g```, ```Content-Type:application/json```.

Answer (score 0):

According to the best practice described by [Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/js/receive),

Instead of having the service worker referenced in the file resources/views/layouts/master.blade.php

You can include the firebase initialization process in the Firebase messaging service worker (**firebase-messaging-sw.js**)